# Use of "s' with apostrophe

Tags: possessives

Is it really necessary to use **'s** for possessive case when used for things and places? I mean if we say:

> Church marble flooring

It does make sense. I feel that it isn't necessary to put **'s** in this.

> Church's marble flooring

Although the second isn't incorrect either however the first seems to make the complete sense too. Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

Is it really necessary to use 's for possessive case when used for things and places?

---

It is related to meaning. Actually both sentences are correct but the meanings are very different.

**Church marble flooring**... We sell church marble flooring in many styles. (The meaning is churches in general).

as opposed to

**Church's marble flooring**  We would have difficulty to match the Church's marble flooring. I doubt you can find that shade of marble in any quarry still in production.
(The meaning relates to a specific church).